# How to create functional test directory in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to create functional tests in grails. I have integration and unit tests. But i am unable to create functional tests directory. I am using grails 2.4.5 version

Comment: if it helps,there is a functional tests plugin -> `compile "org.grails.plugins:functional-test-development:0.9.4"`

Comment: Thank you. I got it by adding some property in idea.iml file as i am using intellij

Answer (score 2):

Grails 2 does not ship with functional testing capabilities. Noted in the documentation [here](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.3/guide/testing.html#functionalTesting). Using a plugin for functional testing is the recommended practice.

> Grails does not ship with any support for writing functional tests
>   directly, but there are several plugins available for this.
>
> Canoo Webtest - http://grails.org/plugin/webtest
>
> G-Func - http://grails.org/plugin/functional-test
>
> Geb - http://grails.org/plugin/geb
>
> Selenium-RC - http://grails.org/plugin/selenium-rc
>
> WebDriver -http://grails.org/plugin/webdriver
>
> Consult the documentation for each plugin for its capabilities.

Grails 3 does ship with the ability to create functional testing using the Geb framework as documented [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/testing.html#functionalTesting):

> Grails by default ships with support for writing functional tests
>   using the Geb framework. To create a functional test you can use the
>   create-functional-test command which will create a new functional
>   test