# Selecting multiple values with multiple where clauses

Tags: mysql

I want to select multiple column values based on multiple where clauses in SQL. I am not able to do it.

I am trying something like,

```
select c.fname,r.fname from customer as c LEFT JOIN retailer as r ON
r.customer_id = c.id where c.id > 10 OR r.id < 50.
```

Basically I want both my where clauses to get executed one by one and first output(when 'where c.id>10' is executed) should come as c.fname and second output (when 'where r.id<50') in one sql query.

Can it be done ? Please help.

Comment: I can not understand, you want all this in same result ? For both where clause ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
c.fname,
r.fname
CASE WHEN r.id < 50 THEN 'output 1'             
     WHEN c.id > 10 THEN 'output 2' END AS 'OUTPUT_COLUMN'
FROM customer as c 
LEFT JOIN retailer as r 
ON r.customer_id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a union, not a join:

```
select c.fname, 'customer' as type from customer as c where c.id > 10
union
select r.fname, 'retailer' from retailer as r where r.id < 50
```

This would give you the list from both tables, independently from each other, within 1 query.