# ElasticSearch filtering mulitple documents with same term

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not sure how to describe this query so don't know what to look for in the documentation. I will try and demonstrate with a made up example.

You have an inventory of electronic devices with serial numbers
`"serial": "xyz"`

they all have a status e.g

`"status": "faulty"`

or

`"status": "repaired"`

There can be multiple documents with the same serial number. E.g.

`{
 "serial": "xyz"
 "status": "faulty"
 "date": 01-01-2015
}`

and then another doc at a later date

`{
 "serial": "xyz"
 "status": "repaired"
 "date": 01-02-2015
}`

So i want to search my index to show me all serial numbers where there exists a document with status "faulty" AND a document with status "repaired". What is the type of query for that?

Comment: What you have described is basically a `JOIN` query as known in relational databases. This is not possible with ElasticSearch. However you can restructure your index so that it is possible - if your statuses are for example nested objects, then you can have nested query. Another possibility is using parent/child relationship with has-child query. Also you might be able to get results you are looking for by some clever combination of aggregations.

Comment: Thanks for you thoughts Pavel. I was trying to avoid having to restructure my index. Get clever ay? Long shot but ill give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

just curious to check if this query satisfies your need:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "status:faulty OR status:repaired"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, this matches ALL documents with "status:faulty" OR "status:repaired". I am looking for unique "serial" for which there exists at least one document with "serial", "status:faulty" and at least one document with "serial", "status:repaired" within the index

Comment: oh sorry, @deliverable.. probably i didnt get your requirement fully.